# Problems with sending video to FTP

Tags: android, video, upload, ftp

I have the following class:

```
public class CameraReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Cursor cursor;
    private MetodosUtils metodosUtils = new MetodosUtils();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if ((metodosUtils.IsWifiConnection(context) == true) || (metodosUtils.IsMobileConnection(context) == true)) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    metodosUtils.ftpUpload("ftp.exemplo.com.br", "user", "pass", "/Dados", cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(3))
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

The method ftpUpload:

```
public boolean ftpUpload(String server, String username, String password, String diretorio, String filePath, String fileName) {
        boolean retorno = false;
        boolean dirExists = true;
        FTPClient mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        String[] fileExists;
        FTPFile[] ftpFile;
        long filesizeLocal = 0;
        long filesizeFtp = 0;

        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                mFTPClient.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
                mFTPClient.connect(server);
                int reply = mFTPClient.getReplyCode();
                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                    mFTPClient.disconnect();
                    retorno = false;
                }
                if (!mFTPClient.login(username, password)) {
                    mFTPClient.logout();
                }
                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                mFTPClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(500);
                mFTPClient.login(username, password);
                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.setBufferSize(1024000);

                String[] directories = diretorio.split("/");
                for (String dir : directories) {
                    if (!dir.isEmpty()) {
                        if (dirExists) {
                            dirExists = mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);
                        }
                        if (!dirExists) {
                            if (!mFTPClient.makeDirectory(dir)) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Não é possível criar diretório remoto '" +
                                        mFTPClient.getReplyString() + "'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            if (!mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(dir)) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Não é possível acessar o diretório remoto recém-criado '" +
                                        mFTPClient.getReplyString() + "'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(diretorio);
                fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                fileExists = mFTPClient.listNames();
                filesizeLocal = file.length();
                ftpFile = mFTPClient.listFiles(fileName);
                if (ftpFile.length == 1 && ftpFile[0].isFile()) {
                    filesizeFtp = ftpFile[0].getSize();
                }
                // somente executa se o arquivo não existir ou for menor que o que vai ser enviado.
                if ((Arrays.asList(fileExists).contains(fileName) == false) ||
                        ((Arrays.asList(fileExists).contains(fileName) == true) &&
                                (filesizeLocal > filesizeFtp))) {
                    if (mFTPClient.storeFile(fileName, fis) == true) {
                        retorno = true;
                    } else {
                        mFTPClient.deleteFile(fileName);
                        retorno = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    retorno = true; // se o arquivo já existe com mesmo tamanho exclui a pendencia
                }
                fis.close();
                mFTPClient.logout();
                mFTPClient.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error uploading " + " - " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            retorno = true;
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <class android:name=".CameraReceiver" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".utils.CameraReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
                <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_VIDEO" />
                <action android:name="com.android.camera.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

For photos taken with the camera are works perfectly, the problem is in the videos, because after a video recorded with the camera, it is sent without the extension for FTP. I've tried to put the extension on the file manually, and yet it does not open.

Comment: 'extension for FTP' ??? What is that?

Comment: Sorry friend, i'm from Brazil and not perfectly know english. I mean the extension of the file, the file is sent to the FTP without the extension ".mp4".

Comment: Send to the FTP ? No. Send to the server using FTP protocol. 'I've tried to put the extension on the file manually, and yet it does not open.'. Who tries to open it? Unclear what you are doing.

Comment: @greenapps, I am sending to the server using the FTP protocol with [apache commons library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/). When I record a video, it is being sent as this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMz9l.png). I even copying that file to my computer and manually adding the extension ".mp4" at the end of the file name does not run the video. What I need is the video to be sent over the FTP protocol with the correct name + extension name. Example: video.mp4.